# can't resize root at Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, partition

I've done `lvresize -L 264G 101/root` (was 15GB) but `/dev/mapper/101-root` shows 13Gb. What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate the help!

---

```
root@server1:/home/user# df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/101-root   13G  2.5G  9.5G  21% /
udev                 621M  4.0K  621M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 252M  296K  251M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  629M     0  629M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1             228M   26M  191M  12% /boot
```

---

```
root@server1:/home/user# lvs
LV     VG   Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
root   101  -wi-ao 464.00g                                      
swap_1 101  -wi-ao   1.25g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lvresize resize only LVM volume, but in df you view size of partition(ext4)
you mast also resize partiton(not all partition support online resize).

```
# lvextend -L 20G VolGroup00/lvolhome (or lvresize -L +5G VolGroup00/lvolhome)
# resize2fs /dev/VolGroup00/lvolhome
```

Comment: Some terminology: It's the file system that needs to be resized, you don't usually have a partition table inside a logical volume.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a `lvresize` is not sufficient, you need to enlarge the file system as well. How this is done is dependent on the type of filesystem (e.g. with `xfs_growfs` for XFS or `resize2fs` for ext3/ext4).

Make sure you have a backup before doing this.